# Referral program do not work in branch.io android

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play-services, branch.io

io to make a referral program for my android app.I integrated according to branch documentation described here https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/guide/android/

And install tracking and giving reward to user is working fine but if i install using a user referral link it do not work.it do not give reward to Influencers.

Here my code

In manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="io.branch.referral.BranchApp"
    >

    <activity android:name="com.video.watch.earn.ActivityMain"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="videotopro" android:host="open" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

```
    <receiver android:name="io.branch.referral.InstallListener" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

In java class MainActivity

```
//branch io

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    final Branch branch = Branch.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

    branch.initSession(new Branch.BranchReferralInitListener(){
        @Override
        public void onInitFinished(JSONObject referringParams, BranchError error) {
            if (error == null) {
                // params are the deep linked params associated with the link that the user clicked -> was re-directed to this app
                // params will be empty if no data found
                // ... insert custom logic here ...
                Log.i("BranchConfigTest", "deep link data: " + referringParams.toString());
            } else {
                Log.i("MyApp", error.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }, this.getIntent().getData(), this);


    String userID = new BigInteger(130, new SecureRandom()).toString(32);
    branch.getInstance().setIdentity(userID);

    Branch.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext()).loadRewards(new Branch.BranchReferralStateChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(boolean changed, BranchError error) {
            int credits = branch.getCredits();
            Log.d("branch credit",""+credits);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    this.setIntent(intent);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Branch.getInstance().logout();
}


//branch io
```

And in my frament I am generating referral link which I share

```
BranchUniversalObject branchUniversalObject = new BranchUniversalObject()
            .setCanonicalIdentifier("item/12345")
            .setTitle("My Content Title")
            .setContentDescription("My Content Description")
            .setContentImageUrl("https://example.com/mycontent-12345.png")
            .setContentIndexingMode(BranchUniversalObject.CONTENT_INDEX_MODE.PUBLIC)
            .addContentMetadata("property1", "blue")
            .addContentMetadata("property2", "red");

    LinkProperties linkProperties = new LinkProperties()
            .setChannel("facebook")
            .setFeature("referral")
            .addControlParameter("$android_url", "http://hkpsourcing.com/vidcoin/app-release.apk");


    branchUniversalObject.generateShortUrl(getActivity(), linkProperties, new Branch.BranchLinkCreateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLinkCreate(String url, BranchError error) {
            if (error == null) {
                Log.i("MyApp", "got my Branch link to share: " + url);
                refUrl=url;
            }
        }
    });
```

I made rule for referrer and referring user but when user install app using referral link it do not track influencers who refer him.

Answer (score 0):

Alex from Branch.io here:

If you're testing on the same devices, you will need to [enable debug mode](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/integration-testing/guide/android/#use-debug-mode-to-simulate-fresh-installs) to trigger fresh installs for this. Otherwise, Branch detects that the app has previously been installed on the device and instead counts that as a `reopen` event to protect against fraud.

Comment: Hi Alex, i am trying the same thing and testing my app in debug mode but it still does not update the credit & i am uninstalling the app in the same device. In the dashboard, in LiveView tab it shows me the referred session but nothing happens in credit tab.

Comment: @Gautam send a ticket in to our [Integrations team](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new), and they should be able to sort this out for you!

Comment: Thanks Alex for the quick response.Sure i will do that